# How can i do that mysqli query with PDO?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am try to build with recursive function that show option menu categories doing indent.
It is working perfect in mysqli query, but how can i do that in PDO query?

For any helps thanks.

I am changed some lines and i also changed correct database connection to PDO, but not worked.

*changed lines:*

```
$dbc = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY title");
$dbc->execute(array());

while (list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $dbc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

My mysqli query need change to PDO:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");

echo '<select name="parent_id">
      <option value="">Select</option>';

function make_list ($parent,$depth) {

    global $option;


    foreach ($parent as $id => $cat) {

        $whitespace = str_repeat(' - ', $depth * 1);
        echo '<option value="' . $cat['id'] . '">'. $whitespace . $cat['category'] . '</option>';

        if (isset($option[$id])) {

            make_list($option[$id], $depth+1);

        }
    }
}

$dbc = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY title");

$option = array();

while (list($id, $parent_id, $category) = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    $option[$parent_id][$id] =  array('category' => $category, 'id' => $id, 'parent_id' => $parent_id);

}
make_list($option[0], $depth = 0);

echo '</select>';
```

Here error messages:

**Line 36 :  foreach ($parent as $id => $cat) {**

**Line 56: while (list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $dbc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {**

**Line 58:     $option[$parent_id][$id] =  array('category' => $category, 'id' => $id, 'parent_id' => $parent_id);**

**Line 61: make_list($option[0], $depth = 0);**

```
<select name="parent_id">
      <option value="">Select</option><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal offset type in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>58</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>56</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/Users/test/Documents/functions/pdo-optionmenu.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working with the given code? "Not worked" is a pretty broad description

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have *no* insecure data in your query, there's no need to use `prepare`, use simple `query` function:

```
$dbc = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY title");
```

Next, `fetchAll` fetches **all** results immediately. You need to fetch row by row. In case of [`query`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), this can be done as

```
foreach ($dbc as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Or with [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method:

```
while ($row = $dbc->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: if i call direct  optionmenu.php.  all menu items  corectly showing, but if i call admin/admin.php?page=optionmenu.   only catID=0 items will be show, do you know why is it?